# UWP: Storyboard for Blinking Text in ListView or ItemsControl

Tags: c#, listview, storyboard, uwp, windows-10-universal

Few months ago, from this forum, I've learned about Storyboard, and I've been using it quite heavily on my application. Now, I hit another road block that I hope you can help me.

I need to do blinking animation inside an ItemsControl or ListView when the order status is changed. It works fine if I need to change the animation to blinking. The question is how do I stop it.

Here is my code:

```
<Viewbox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ic:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Cancelled">
            <im:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play">
                <im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="lblOrderStatus"
                                         From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
             </im:ControlStoryboardAction>
         </ic:DataTriggerBehavior>
         <ic:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" ComparisonCondition="NotEqual" Value="Cancelled">
             <im:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Stop">
                 <im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="lblOrderStatus"
                                          From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                     </Storyboard>
                 </im:ControlStoryboardAction.Storyboard>
             </im:ControlStoryboardAction>
         </ic:DataTriggerBehavior>
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <TextBlock x:Name="lblOrderStatus" Text="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
 </Viewbox>
```

As you can see, I have two triggers. When the OrderStatus changed to **Cancelled**, it will run animation. But when the OrderStatus changed to **Acknowledge** or anything else, the animation is still running. ***This is because it is actually 2 separates storyboards.***

I have tried to use **StaticResource**, but it only change the first row.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Viewbox.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="sbBlinking">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)"
                             Storyboard.TargetName="lblOrderStatus"
                             From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Viewbox.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ic:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Cancelled">
            <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource sbBlinking}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play" />
        </ic:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <ic:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}" ComparisonCondition="NotEqual" Value="Cancelled">
            <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource sbBlinking}" ControlStoryboardOption="Stop" />
        </ic:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblOrderStatus" Text="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```

Any idea on how to tackle this problem? Thanks again...

Comment: You should be able to combine two `Storyboard`s into one.

Comment: @JustinXL - yes, love to do that. But I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: As far as I know `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` means that the animation will be repeated forever.  This may cause the animation can't stop.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, yes, the purpose is to keep repeating the animation until the status is changed. So the text is blinking forever while on **Cancelled** status and only stop when the status is NOT **Cancelled** (eg. **Acknowledge**).